# quota sampling method and response rate

Tags: sampling

I cannot understand it intuitively because quota sample means you just collect samples until each sample criterion is filled. Meanwhile, response rate means the proportion of people who refused to participate. So, what should I use as the denominator when calculating the response rate in quota sampling method?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Quota sampling is not a probabilistic method, so the [AAPOR concepts of response rates](http://www.aapor.org/Standards-Ethics/Standard-Definitions-(1).aspx) are not applicable. You don't know what your denominators really are, and what the eligibility corrections should be.

You can fake some sort of "participation rate" or whatever, but your obligation as a researcher is to put the first sentence of this answer into your report as is.